# How to obtain the consecutive numbers between two numbers in rows in excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need your help on this issue whether the solution is from excel formula, power query or macros.

I have a list of products which have a start and ending serials numbers and I would like to have automatically the list of serial numbers by rows in excel for each product based on their respective start and ending numbers.

Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Comment: Depending on your version, try `=sequence`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the leftmost table was loaded into powerquery (data ... from table range,  [x] column headers) add column ... custom column ... with formula

```
= {[Start Serial] ... [End Serial]}
```

then use arrows atop the column to expand into rows. File close and load

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain your desired output using Power Query,

• Select any cell in your original table,

• Data --> Get & Transform Data --> From Table/Range or From within sheet,

• When the PQ Editor opens, navigate to Home --> Advanced Editor,

• Make note of the Table Name in Line 2 of the code,

• Replace the existing code with the M-Code below,

• Change the table name in line 2 of the pasted code to your "real" table name

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Item", type text}, {"Start Serial", Int64.Type}, {"End Serial", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each {[Start Serial]..[End Serial]}),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"Start Serial", "End Serial"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks lot Mayukh. It works absolutely fine. You saved my life! God bless.

Comment: hello how do i accept it as an answer?